# Древовидная структура, быстрая конкатенация строк

Tags: java, строки, структуры-данных, дерево

Нужен аналог StringBuilder в Java, который конкатенирует 2 StringBuilder'а за O(1). Изначально написал свой LinkedList на символах, который конкатенирует 2 листа просто перекидывая указатели, однако это решение оказалось неэффективным, так как где-то наплодилось много указателей. Мой учитель подсказал мне сделать древовидную структуру(возможно она была придумана им самим), которая конкатенирует строки путем создания новой вершины у которой левый сын это вершина отвечающая за левую строку, а правый за правую строку(то есть чтобы восстановить строку, надо спуститься влево, потом вправо). Интересно, как это реализовать так, чтобы было сильно эффективнее чем связный список.